# Screen locked after screensaver blank screen only

Tags: touchscreen, login, screen-saver

Using xscreensaver I'm trying to suspend/blank the screen (essentially turn it off to save power) without locking but I don't seem to be able to do this. I'm using the official 7" touchscreen.

I have the following settings:

Display Modes:

- Mode: Blank Screen Only
- Blank After: 2 minutes
- Cycle After: 0 minutes
- Lock Screen After: un-checked (0 minutes) - I thought this would stop the screen from locking.

Advanced > Display Power Management:

- Power Management Enabled: checked
- Standby After: 2 minutes
- Suspend After: 2 minutes
- Off After: 2 minutes
- Quick Power-off in Blank Only Mode: checked

The screen goes blank and I believe turns off successfully but if I don't immediately touch the screen then it will give me a login screen.

Alternatively if I uncheck "Display Power Management" the screen goes blank and doesn't lock but I believe it's still drawing power, the backlight looks light it's on.

How do I save power without locking the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution by changing settings. I suspect it was light-locker configuration so I uninstalled it. I also uninstalled lxlock.

Not the most ideal solution but it solves my needs.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.